# Внешние ключи и FileTables

Tags: sql-server

Есть первая таблица people, в ней есть столбец photo - uniqueidentifier.
Вторая - FileTable photo.

Первая таблица связана (photo) со второй (stream_id), и в случае, если фотография будет удалена, столбцу photo будет присвоен NULL.

А как сделать, чтобы в случае удаления человека из таблицы people удалялась и фотография? Пытался присвоить внешний ключ обычным способом, но не хочет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Первая таблица связана (photo) со второй (stream_id), и в случае, если
>   фотография будет удалена, то столбцу photo будет присвоен Null.

В таком случае обычный `AFTER DELETE` триггер должен сработать

```
CREATE TRIGGER people_afterDelete
ON people
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE PH
    FROM photo PH
        JOIN DELETED D on D.photo = PH.stream_id;

END;
```

И то, что таблица `photo` является *FileTable*, никакой роли в данном случае не играет.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный совет - разверните ассоциацию в обратную сторону: вместо указания id фотографии в таблице людей указывайте id человека в таблице фотографий.

Если же вам требуется гарантировать что более 1 фотографии у человека нет, вообще уберите дополнительные поля и связывайте две таблицы 1 к 0..1 по первичным ключам.